# given a MatrixTransform how do I determine its current angle?

Tags: c#, wpf, transform

I'm using WPF's MatrixTransform for managing my translation, scaling, and rotation on a Canvas (all 2D). It works well. However, I would like to be able to calculate the current angle of rotation. How is this done? Do I need to invert the matrix and then use that to rotate something? I can provide a "rotation-at" point if necessary.

Comment: Unless the matrix is exacty a rotate transform matrix (ie: has the proper symmetries), then there isn't an "angle" for the transformation, per se.  You would have to define what you mean - if the transform distorts the original then where do you reference your angle?  Imagine that the matrix takes a square and moves only one of the vertices - how has its "angle" changed?

Comment: If you can replace the MatrixTransform with a TransformGroup containing other transforms (Rotate, Translate, Scale, Skew, etc.), you might be able to find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

1. The matrix is definitely a translation/rotation/scale matrix (no skew or other non-orthogonality).
2. The matrix is specified such that scale is applied first, followed by rotation, followed by translation.

Steps:

1. You can ignore the final translation component, giving you the upper left 3x3 matrix that contains scale and rotation.
2. Scaling is just multiplication by a diagonal matrix of scaling factors (scaling each column in the matrix), so you can normalize the column vectors to give you an orthonormal matrix that purely expresses rotation.
3. To get an angle of rotation, you either need to choose an axis of rotation or a vector you want to rotate (from which you can compute a rotation axis and angle.)

The latter case is easier:

1. Take a sample vector v with magnitude 1 (simplifies the math.)
2. Transform by the rotation matrix to get v'.
3. For the rotation axis (v x v'), the angle between them is defined as acos(v * v').  'x' is the cross product and '*' is the dot product.

Comment: It appears to work by just zeroing the OffsetX/Y; no scaling is needed as vector length doesn't change the angle. Thanks for the quick response. E.g. 

`var mWithoutOffset = m; // it's a struct (copied by assignment)
mWithoutOffset.OffsetX = mWithoutOffset.OffsetY = 0.0;
var vector = mWithoutOffset.Transform(new Vector(1.0, 0.0));
var currentRotation = Math.Atan2(vector.Y, vector.X) * Constants.RAD_TO_DEG + 90.0;
var assetAngle = ((double) _headingVal) * Constants.RAD_TO_DEG;
m.RotateAt(assetAngle - currentRotation, ActualWidth * 0.5, ActualHeight * 0.5);`

Comment: @Brannon, ah, I completely missed that this was 2D.  In that case, yeah, there is one unique angle of rotation.